# What is this thing behind my oilpan and is it bad that it's cracked?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission

Sorry I can't be more specific. I have no idea what it is and my google-fu has failed me.

[image] Here is an image of the part in question. It is in the center of the image and has a large crack in it.

What is it and if it's bad that it's cracked, then could a little bit of welding help me out?

EDIT: 1994 Cherokee if that matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the supports for the transmission. On a Cherokee (Jeep XJ), the engine, clutch, gearbox and transfer case form a complete assembly that goes inline from front to rear. Needless to say, this is quite long and needs some support points to bear the weight.

Even if this is just one support point among many (and the others can hold things in place), it is best to change it. The complete transmission weighs quite a lot, and you do not want it shimmying all over the place when you drive.

On the other hand, a Cherokee is also designed for off-roading, where stresses can get higher than on-road. Components can be seen as over-engineered for simply driving on the highway. So while it will certainly be best to have it changed, there is probably no immediate hurry to do so.

The biggest hindrance to take it out will probably be a bit of rust in the bolts, since may have been taken out just 1-2 times during the life of the vehicle (whenever the clutch has been changed on a manual - maybe never on an automatic box). So I would recommend a dose of penetrating lubricant applied some time before actually wrenching (12-24 hours). WD-40 comes to mind.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.  On a side note, you pointed out specifically that the engine, clutch, gearbox, and transfer case form a complete assembly.  Just out of curiosity, is that an unusual design?

Answer (score 3):

Looked at it with my father-in-law and he says it's the [rear transmission mount](http://www.jeep4x4center.com/automatic-transmission-mount-52002334.html).  Also turns out it's rubber, not metal (didn't think to check that because I'm an idiot).

He said it's not a huge deal that it's torn, but obviously it would be better if I replaced it. It's a cheap part and shouldn't he a huge deal to fix.

I reckon I can just put a jack stand underneath the transmission, unbolt the old mount, pry it out, then place the new one in and bolt everything back together.

Answer (score 1):

It is a transmission mount. You can change it easily apparently :) You can see it clearly in the video below.

See this video:
Replacing Transmission Mount - Jeep Cherokee

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyBmh-DF6sc

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing what else it's connected to. However if I had to guess, it looks like a portion of your subframe.

A subframe is a piece of metal that typically stretches from one side of your car to the other and is bolted to the actual frame of your car. Its task is to support the weight of your engine and transmission.

Although I can't see the crack (it might help to take a closer, more detailed photo of the crack itself) I would say that if it involves the subframe and the crack is substantial, yes, it is a bad thing. If, when driving, the subframe cracks in half, there's very little support for a ~300+lb smorgasbord of cast iron and steel parts.

With that said, don't be TOO worried. Bring it somewhere like a Monro or something and have them lift it up and get their opinion (don't necessary have them do the work, their labor rates are high and depending on the mechanic, may not be qualified). Bottom line, get it up on a lift, get someone's opinion and take **many** photos of it. There are **a lot** of forums about jeeps or cars in general who can give you better insight.